# Monitoring page cache / memory mapped files access

Tags: strace, mmap

I have an app that uses multiple memory mapped files. If I check the major page faults numbers (with `/proc/<pid>/stat`), they skyrocket.

I was wondering if it's possible to monitor somehow what memory mapped files are affected by the page swap ins and outs for a process?

At least I would like to see see what mmap-ed files are accessed for a process. I tried with strace, but I found no reads, because I guess no system calls are needed for the direct access to memory.

I would be happy also to know the virtual address in process space where they happen, so at least I could map them manually to the files in pmap output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perf trace -F maj
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-trace.1.html

To connect to an existing process, use `-p $PID`.  If you don't want to show system calls, pass `--no-syscalls` as well.  The system call arguments won't be shown with the same level of detail as `strace`.

Comment: It seems we don't have perf trace, but we have perf record. It seems it's similar...

Comment: with the peft record tool , I get this output while processing the log with perf script

`myprocess 28050 major-faults:          32301f2b  ()
myprocess 28050 major-faults:          3239df34  ()
myprocess 28050 major-faults:          3239df34  ()`

are the numbers in the last columns the info I'm looking for?

Comment: @jackmalkovick hmm, I've seen this output before https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434171/perf-shows-page-faults-which-are-neither-minor-nor-major I'm not really sure what to guess about your output, except to say that I think the `()` part is normally supposed to show a filename.

Comment: I'd wonder a bit whether you're using a JIT language like Java, then I'd guess that the file indications in perf script refer to the faulting instruction (when what you want is the address inside the page that is being faulted in), and in your case the instruction is in anonymous memory.

Comment: Uh... yes. I'm using Java. I expected to see the virtual memory address where the page fault happen, not the address of the instruction that produced it. With the address I can match it to a file using pmap

Comment: @jackmalkovick sounds like you get to build `perf trace` from source :-P. I tested `perf trace` before i suggested it, and it does show the data file as desired.

Comment: Sourcejedi are you sure that perf trace will display the correct major page fault address for my Java process? Is this a scenario that you tried? We are using SUSE and the admin told me only perf record is available there...

Comment: It looks very much like it shows the target file and an offset into it. (for heap/anon, it looks like it might show the full address instead?) I have no reason to think the offset is inaccurate.  I suppose `perf trace` does depend on having the right events available in the kernel. `perf trace record` + `perf report` suggests that the event name used would be `major-faults`, like you already have. I guess this is a perf event and not an older-style tracepoint. You can list the events available to perf with `perf-list`. I would tend to assume the data passed with the event has not changed.

Comment: although, using `perf trace -i` on a file generated with `perf trace record` doesn't know where the fault address was (shows `=> 0x0 (?.)`).  So maybe this is a bit special and the event might not have the needed data on your kernel version, I dunno. My `perf` version is 4.16.0.

Comment: If your kernel is not too antiquated, there is an x86-specific _tracepoint_ for page faults. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/d34603b07c4255b2b00a546d34f297ccd50ae4c6

Comment: Used PreserveFramePointer for JVM and got something like  `7fa0d94fa876 JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) /usr/local/ingenuity/jdk1.8.0_172/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so)` So definitely it's showing where in the (java) code and what file (the java lib) the fault is produced